# Suppose $U_1,\dots,U_k$ and $V_1,\dots,V_k$ are $n\times n$ unitary matrices. Show that $\|U_1\cdots U_k-V_1\cdots V_k\|\leq\sum_{i=1}^k\|U_i-V_i\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $V,W$ be  complex inner product spaces. Suppose $T: V \to W$ is a linear map, then we define 
$$\|T\|:=\sup\{\|Tv\|_{W}:\|v\|_{V}=1\}$$ where $\|v\_{V}\|:=\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}$ and $\|Tv\|_{W}:=\sqrt{\langle Tv,Tv\rangle}$.

**Question:** Suppose $U_1,\ldots,U_k$ and $V_1,\ldots,V_k$ are $n {\times} n$ unitary matrices. Show that 
$$\|U_1\cdots U_k-V_1\cdots V_k\| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{k}\|U_i-V_i\|$$

I have tried to use triangle inequality for norms and induction but failed. Can anyone give some hints? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $k = 1$, the inequality becomes an identity.  So, start with the special case $k = 2$:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
& ||U_1 U_2 - V_1 V_2||\\ \\
= & ||U_1 U_2 - V_1 U_2  + V_1 U_2 - V_1 V_2||\\ \\
= &
|| ( U_1 - V_1) U_2  + V_1 (U_2 - V_2) || \\ \\
\leq & ||( U_1 - V_1) U_2 || + ||V_1 (U_2 - V_2) ||.\\
\end{array}
$$
(The last inequality is the triangle inequality.)  Now, since $U_2$ is unitary, we have $||U_{2}|| = 1$, so
$$
|| ( U_1 - V_1) U_2 || \leq || U_1 - V_1 ||.
$$
A similar bound obtains for $||V_1 (U_2 - V_2) ||$.

This should give you enough "building blocks".:)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome.  I edited to remove the (unjustified) assumption that the matrices commute.:)